# Chrome console show object properties instead of DOM tree

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am used to work with Firefox as it has quite a much useful features. However I need to start working with chrome and it is a struggle

What I need is to show propertes of an object in console. How to achieve that?
Firefox - what I need

[image]

Chrome - what it does is useless
[image]

So how to achieve the same behavior, or at least where to get to properties of such listed object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just select a DOM element using inspector or focusing an element. You will find a properties tab on chrome DevTool. You will find all the properties of the selected object.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this seems like it can work for me for now .... you have to list element into the console as on my screen, then you have to right click, the hit Reveal in Elements panel and then view the properties ... may the usability lives ... but thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change this behavior.

You can, however, work around it (for most use cases): Right-click on the desired element, select “Reveal in Elements panel”. It will then be selected and you can go to “Properties” in the right properties pane.

This doesn’t cover use cases where the logged element is not currently part of the DOM. To deal with those, use `console.dir` instead of `console.log`:

```
console.dir(document)
```